# How to change volume balance for headphones?

Tags: audio, volume-control, volume

I am using a Moto Z2 Play, unrooted. One ear is louder than the other and i have discovered thaf it isnt the earbuds. How can I change the volume balance on my earbuds?

Comment: Without root, this isn't possible. If you choose to root, you can find lots of apps.

Comment: BTW, in older Android versions, Audio Balance was there in Accessibility Settings. Now, they have removed it. Only Mono option remains for the people who are deaf in one ear.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a 4 pin jack ( Left Speaker Positive, Right Speaker Positive, Ground, Microphone Positive )

If your headphones are three pin, you may have a misaligned connection with one of the speakers...

Here's an example of what i mean by 4 pin .

[image: 4 Pin Jack]

You can see the problem with the 3 Pin headphones fitting here...

So you can either buy an adapter, make an adapter etc...

If you are sure your PINs are aligning properly, you can rule this out and then continue..

In my experience developing music players for background applications, you can not set the volume without using a value for both the left speak and right speaker, For this reason, most developers use a single float value and apply it as both volumes... The developer would need to make a music player that allows independent volume setting, or a set volume difference on a per-app basis.

Comment: Ok. Thanks, man. This super annoying and ill try and get a different pair of earbuds.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Moto Z2, but on Samsung devices, there is an Accessibility settings regarding this. Uou can check it on Settings > Accessibility > Sound Balance > and adjust the sound balance to your needs.